# How to display an HTML list non-nested?

Tags: html, css

Here's the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Salads</li>
    <li>Fruits
        <ul>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Prunes</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Course</li>
</ul>
```

Here's what it looks like now:

```
Salads Fruits
   Apples Prunes
Main Course
```

And here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
Salads Fruits Main Course
Apples Prunes
```

How can I achieve this, *without* modifying the HTML?

Current CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;   
    display:block;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If Salads or Main Course have children, show how you want the results to appear then.  One the same line with Apples and Prunes or different lines?

Comment: @Khnle: Only one of the top elements is ever going to have children. I'm using it for a menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This results in the display:

```
Salads Fruits Main Course
      Apples Prunes
```

Here is the CSS I used.

```
ul {
    list-style:none;   
    display:block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

If you don't want the individual fruits to start a little way across the page - remove the padding with this style rule:

```
ul > li > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

All of the above will still work if you nest more items too. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Salads
        <ul>
            <li>Green Leaf</li>
            <li>Chicken</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fruits
        <ul>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Prunes</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main Course</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A quick test using browsershots.org showed that this works even for older browsers. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You should style the `ul` inside the `li`, and the `li` inside the `ul`,

[View demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/s6yup/2). I hope it helps.

CSS for a quick look:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;   
    display:block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
ul > li > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This layout breaks when the text lengths change.

Comment: After some more testing, I came up with the same answer as Sohnee check: http://jsfiddle.net/s6yup/2/

Answer (score -1):

you will need to apply styles to the ULs INSIDE the lis. Try this out

```
ul li    {
    float: left;        
}
```

Comment: This results in a big gap in the top row.